# How can I force Spring to serialize my controller's @ResponseBody as the method's declared return type?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I am attempting to use interfaces to define flexible response bodies from my Spring controllers.

**What I expect**: When I call an endpoint using Curl/Postman/etc, I should receive JSON objects that contain only the fields visible in the interface that the controller returns.

**What I'm getting**: When I call either endpoint, I receive JSON objects with every field defined in my entity.

Let's say my entity looks like this:

`MyEntity.java`

```
public class MyEntity implements ListEntityResponse, GetEntityResponse {
    int dbid;
    String name;
    String description;

    public int getDbid() { return dbid; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
}
```

Let's say `MyEntity` has many more fields that include complex data types that aren't suitable for serialization as part of a large list, or for certain other use cases. To solve this problem, I've created interfaces to limit which fields are visible in the response object. In this example, the first interface only defines two of the three getters, while the second interface defines all of them.

`ListEntityResponse` interface:

```
public interface ListEntityResponse {
    int getDbid();
    String getName();
}
```

`GetEntityResponse` interface:

```
public interface GetEntityResponse {
    int getDbid();
    String getName();
    String getDescription();
}
```

And finally, here are my controllers. The important part is that each defines its return type as one of the interfaces:

`ListEntityController`

```
    @GetMapping(path="/{name}")
    public @ResponseBody List<ListEntityResponse> getList() {
        return handler.getList(name);
    }
```

`GetEntityController`

```
    @GetMapping(path="/{name}")
    public @ResponseBody GetEntityResponse getByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return handler.getByName(name);
    }
```

To recap, if we assume that our handler returns `MyEntity` objects, then I want that object to be serialized by Spring as the interface defined in the controller's return type. E.G. each JSON object in the list returned by the `ListEntityController` should have only the `dbid` and `name` fields. Unfortunately, that's not happening, and the returned JSON objects have every field available despite being masked as interface objects.

I have attempted to add `@JsonSerialize(as = ListEntityResponse.class)` to my first interface, and a similar annotation to the second. This works *only* if the entity implements just one of those interfaces. Once the entity implements multiple interfaces, each annotated with `@JsonSerialize`, Spring will serialize it as the first interface in the list regardless of the controller's return type.

How can I force a Spring to always serialize its Controller's responses as the controller function's return type?

**Note:** I am trying to find a solution that **does not** require me to use `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. Additionally, I am trying to find a solution that does not require me to add `@JsonView` to my entity classes. I am willing to use the `@JsonView` annotation in the interfaces, but don't see a clean and maintainable way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force Spring to always serialize its controller's responses as
> the controller function's return type?
>
> Please note that I am not interested in using `@JsonIgnore`,
> `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, or `@JsonView` to provide the view masking that I
> require. They do not fit my use case.

One of the options would be to create a thin wrapper over `MyEntity` class, which would be responsible for providing the required serialization-shape.

Every shape would be represented by its own wrapper, implemented as a single-field class. To specify serialization-shape, we can use [`as`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#as--) property of the [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation, by assigning the target interface as a value. And since we don't need the wrapper itself to reflected in the resulting JSON, we can make use of the [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation.

Here's a wrapper for `GetEntityResponse` shape:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GetEntityResponseWrapper implements EntityWrapper {
    @JsonSerialize(as = GetEntityResponse.class)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private MyEntity entity;
}
```

And that's a wrapper for `ListEntityResponse` shape:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ListEntityResponseWrapper implements EntityWrapper {
    @JsonSerialize(as = ListEntityResponse.class)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private MyEntity entity;
}
```

Basically, we have finished with serialization logic.

And you can use these lean classes in your controllers as is. But to make the solution more organized and easier to extend, I've introduced a level of abstraction. As you probably noticed both wrapper-classes are implementing `EntityWrapper` interface, its goal is to abstract away the concrete implementation representing shapes from the code in Controllers/Services.

```
public interface EntityWrapper {
    enum Type { LIST_ENTITY, GET_ENTITY } // each type represents a concrete implementation
    
    static EntityWrapper wrap(Type type, MyEntity entity) {
        return switch (type) {
            case LIST_ENTITY -> new ListEntityResponseWrapper(entity);
            case GET_ENTITY -> new GetEntityResponseWrapper(entity);
        };
    }
    
    static List<EntityWrapper> wrapAll(Type type, MyEntity... entities) {
        
        return Arrays.stream(entities)
            .map(entity -> wrap(type, entity))
            .toList();
    }
}
```

Methods `EntityWrapper.wrap()` and `EntityWrapper.wrapAll()` are uniform entry points. We can use an `enum` to represent the target type.

***Note** that* `EntityWrapper` *needs to be used in the return types in your Controller.*

Here the two dummy end-points I've used for testing (*I've removed the path-variables since they are not related to what I'm going to demonstrate*):

```
@GetMapping("/a")
public List<EntityWrapper> getList() {
    // your logic here
    
    return EntityWrapper.wrapAll(
        EntityWrapper.Type.LIST_ENTITY,
        new MyEntity(1, "Alice", "A"),
        new MyEntity(2, "Bob", "B"),
        new MyEntity(3, "Carol", "C")
    );
}

@GetMapping("/b")
public EntityWrapper getByName() {
    // your logic here
    
    return EntityWrapper.wrap(
        EntityWrapper.Type.GET_ENTITY,
        new MyEntity(2, "Bob", "B")
    );
}
```

*Response of the end-point* `"/a"` *(only **two** properties have been serialized):*

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "dbid": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "dbid": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Carol",
        "dbid": 3
    }
]
```

*Response of the end-point* `"/b"` *(all **three** properties have been serialized):*

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "description": "B",
    "dbid": 2
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution for my example case. I've been wracking my brain to see whether it will work for a more complex system that uses generics to abstract away a lot of boilerplate code. E.G. I'd prefer not to have an ever-growing enum in the EntityWrapper class. Unfortunately, I'm coming up empty--type erasure may just be the bane of my existence. Ah, well! Thanks very much, this is extremely helpful!